# Moving a point on a sphere

Tags: spheres

I have a sphere and a point on it. Now I want to move this point in the direction of a randomly choosen angle "a" for for the arc length "l", over the surface of the sphere.

What are the mathematical equations for that?

I thought about maybe using great-circles somehow, but I don't know how to do that practically.

--

I also found this, but it don't applies to my case, because that case is reduced to the use of Vectors:

[Moving a point around a Sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905620/moving-a-point-around-a-sphere)

Comment: How is your point on the sphere represented? Latitude and longitude? Please edit the answer into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given the radius $r$ and the arch length $l$, the angle $\theta$ is given by

$$\theta=\frac l r$$

to define the new position we need to define the rotation axis, expressed by the unit vector $\vec u=(u_x,u_y,u_z)$,  and use the following [Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

$$R = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \theta +u_x^2 \left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_x u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_z \sin \theta & u_x u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_y \sin \theta \\ 
u_y u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_z \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_y^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_y u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_x \sin \theta \\ 
u_z u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_y \sin \theta & u_z u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_x \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_z^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: okay, thank you, but how can I move my point now?

Comment: This answer doesn't look likely to help the OP.

Comment: so, I have my point **(r,θ,ϕ)** and I want to move it by **l** into direction **a**.

Comment: @TonyK Yes I'll try to understand better what the asker is looking for.

Comment: @jackjuni How do you define the direction $\vec a$?

Comment: @gimusi Which unit is θ in this case, radians or degrees or smth else?

Comment: @gimusi So far I define **a** just as degrees.

Comment: @jackjuni Radians of course! To summarize, given $r$ and $l$ and a point on a sphere $P(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ we can define a random $\vec u$ with $\|\vec u\|=1$ and find the new position $P'$ by $R\cdot (x,y,z)^T$.

Comment: @jackjuni It is meaningless define a direction for rotation by a vector $\vec a$ in degrees!The angle is defined once we have $r$ and $l$. To determine the new position we need to define a rotation axis or something else which is equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84585/discussion-between-jackjuni-and-gimusi).