# How do I get $~x,y +$ degrees new coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have

- center of circle's $x_1, y_1$ (called the eye in my code)
- degrees
- current $x_2, y_2$ (coordinates on the circle)

I want to add degrees to the $x_2, y_2$ and get the new "$x_3, y_3$"

Side Note: I dropped out of school and never learned TRIG. So a simple explanation would do wonders.

[image]

Comment: What **exactly** are $\;x,y\;$ ? Is it an ordered pair $\;(x,y)\;$ which is the center of some circle, or something else? And anyway: what does "adding degrees " to point in the plane (or whatever) is?

Comment: I added an image, hopefully that helps

Comment: You use $x,y$ twice.  Once it looks like the center of the circle, and once it looks like a point on the circle.  Please clarify.  It sounds like you have the center of a circle $(x,y)$, a point on the circle $(x_1,y_1)$ and want to find another point on the circle $(x_2,y_2)$ that is a given angle (clockwise, counterclockwise, do you care?) from the first point.  Is this right?  Stating the problem clearly is usually the first step to a solution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814950/how-can-i-rotate-a-coordinate-around-a-circle. I think that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, the drawing did help to make clear your intention: you want to *rotate* the circle on its center to get from a given point on it another point on it...yet I, at least, can't see how to achieve that without some minimal trigonometry and/or linear algebra...

Comment: First time using stackoverflow, edited it

Comment: Yes, show me the minimal Trig, I was just stating I don't know this stuff.

Comment: Then read the linked question and answer by Saswat, above

Comment: It WORKS! Thanks my guys.